# Problem with umlauts in rotated longtable

Tags: longtable, landscape, apa6

I encountered a strange thing when setting up a rotated longtable with `apa6`.

Specifically, this works:

```
\documentclass[12pt
               ,man % manuscript mode; jou man doc
               ,babel, american % language
               %,biblatex % loads biblatex or apacite
               ,a4paper % default:letter
               % ,floatsintext
               ,noextraspace %removes extra space after headings; closer to "true" double-spacing
               %,mask
               ,longtable
               %,helv % font in man mode
               %,tt   % font in man mode
               %,draftfirst
               %,draftall
               ]{apa6}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}


%% for the huge table to avoid boxes warnings
\newcommand{\rr}{\raggedright}
\newcommand{\tn}{\tabularnewline}


\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor*{landscape}{table}


\title{Longtables and Me: An Endless Story}
\shorttitle{Longtables}

\author{Me}
\affiliation{MeU}

\authornote{
Empty
}



\abstract{
Empty.
}


\keywords{Empty}





\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{landscape}

\begin{ThreePartTable}

\begin{TableNotes}
\rr \footnotesize %
\textit{Note.} 
Just a TableNote to explain some stuff.
\end{TableNotes}


\begin{longtable}{p{7.3cm}
                  S[table-format = 5]
                  l
                  l
                  S[table-format = 2.2]
                  c
                  p{5cm}}

\caption{Longitudinal Studies Included in the Analysis} \\
\label{tab:studies} \\

\toprule
1st Column  & {2nd Column}  &  3rd Column   &  4th Column  &  {5th Column}  &  6th  &  7th Column\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead


\multicolumn{7}{l}{{\tablename} \thetable{} (continued)} \\[0.5ex]

\toprule
1st Column  & {2nd Column}  &  3rd Column   &  4th Column  &  {5th Column}  &  6th  &  7th Column\\
\midrule
\endhead

\rr An Entry    & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry that is quite long and breaks to the next line   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr Another rather long Entry that also breaks and extends over two lines   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\


\bottomrule

\insertTableNotes

\end{longtable}

\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{landscape}


\lipsum


\end{document}
```

Inserting an umlaut in one of the table cells (first line, left column) breaks everything and yields an error:

```
\documentclass[12pt
               ,man % manuscript mode; jou man doc
               ,babel, american % language
               %,biblatex % loads biblatex or apacite
               ,a4paper % default:letter
               % ,floatsintext
               ,noextraspace %removes extra space after headings; closer to "true" double-spacing
               %,mask
               ,longtable
               %,helv % font in man mode
               %,tt   % font in man mode
               %,draftfirst
               %,draftall
               ]{apa6}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}


%% for the huge table to avoid boxes warnings
\newcommand{\rr}{\raggedright}
\newcommand{\tn}{\tabularnewline}


\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor*{landscape}{table}


\title{Longtables and Me: An Endless Story}
\shorttitle{Longtables}

\author{Me}
\affiliation{MeU}

\authornote{
Empty
}



\abstract{
Empty.
}


\keywords{Empty}





\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{landscape}

\begin{ThreePartTable}

\begin{TableNotes}
\rr \footnotesize %
\textit{Note.} 
Just a TableNote to explain some stuff.
\end{TableNotes}


\begin{longtable}{p{7.3cm}
                  S[table-format = 5]
                  l
                  l
                  S[table-format = 2.2]
                  c
                  p{5cm}}

\caption{Longitudinal Studies Included in the Analysis} \\
\label{tab:studies} \\

\toprule
1st Column  & {2nd Column}  &  3rd Column   &  4th Column  &  {5th Column}  &  6th  &  7th Column\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead


\multicolumn{7}{l}{{\tablename} \thetable{} (continued)} \\[0.5ex]

\toprule
1st Column  & {2nd Column}  &  3rd Column   &  4th Column  &  {5th Column}  &  6th  &  7th Column\\
\midrule
\endhead

\rr An Entry with ä    & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry that is quite long and breaks to the next line   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr Another rather long Entry that also breaks and extends over two lines   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\


\bottomrule

\insertTableNotes

\end{longtable}

\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{landscape}


\lipsum


\end{document}
```

Interestingly, if I remove `\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor*{landscape}{table}` from the preamble, everything works again (however, I need to keep this command).

Of course, the problem can be circumvented easily by escaping umlauts and speicl characters (e.g., `\"a` in this case), but I wondered if there is a more general solution for this context.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: umlauts work properly outside the rotated longtable.

Comment: Well, as you note, there is always `An Entry with \"a`; or else `An Entry with \detokenize{ä}` or `An Entry with \string ä `

Comment: Note the `.ttt` file gets written out with a latin 1 encoding.  Switching your document encoding to latin 1, circumvents the problem.

Comment: Where and/or how is the macro `\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor*` defined?

Comment: @AndrewSwann thanks, I didn't know that. Maybe that's indeed the culprit.

Comment: @Mico `DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor*` comes from the `endfloat` package, which is automatically loaded with `apa6`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason I don't understand, the temporary file where the delayed table is written out is encoded in latin 1 rather than utf8.  A work around is thus to set the input encoding to latin 1 when the table is read in again.  You can conveniently do this with

```
\AtBeginDelayedFloats{\inputencoding{latin1}}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt
               ,man % manuscript mode; jou man doc
               ,babel, american % language
               %,biblatex % loads biblatex or apacite
               ,a4paper % default:letter
               % ,floatsintext
               ,noextraspace %removes extra space after headings; closer to "true" double-spacing
               %,mask
               ,longtable
               %,helv % font in man mode
               %,tt   % font in man mode
               %,draftfirst
               %,draftall
               ]{apa6}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}


%% for the huge table to avoid boxes warnings
\newcommand{\rr}{\raggedright}
\newcommand{\tn}{\tabularnewline}


\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor*{landscape}{table}
\AtBeginDelayedFloats{\inputencoding{latin1}}

\title{Longtables and Me: An Endless Story}
\shorttitle{Longtables}

\author{Me}
\affiliation{MeU}

\authornote{
Empty
}



\abstract{
Empty.
}


\keywords{Empty}





\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{landscape}

\begin{ThreePartTable}

\begin{TableNotes}
\rr \footnotesize %
\textit{Note.}
Just a TableNote to explain some stuff.
\end{TableNotes}


\begin{longtable}{p{7.3cm}
                  S[table-format = 5]
                  l
                  l
                  S[table-format = 2.2]
                  c
                  p{5cm}}

\caption{Longitudinal Studies Included in the Analysis} \\
\label{tab:studies} \\

\toprule
1st Column  & {2nd Column}  &  3rd Column   &  4th Column  &  {5th Column}  &  6th  &  7th Column\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead


\multicolumn{7}{l}{{\tablename} \thetable{} (continued)} \\[0.5ex]

\toprule
1st Column  & {2nd Column}  &  3rd Column   &  4th Column  &  {5th Column}  &  6th  &  7th Column\\
\midrule
\endhead

\rr An Entry with ä    & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry that is quite long and breaks to the next line   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr Another rather long Entry that also breaks and extends over two lines   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\

\rr An Entry   & 1234  & ABCD    & glo  & 99.32  & 2  & Some more text \\


\bottomrule

\insertTableNotes

\end{longtable}

\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{landscape}


\lipsum


\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably because of the method of writing within `endfloat`. Don't we need something like `\protected@write` for utf8 to be written correctly to disk?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to inform the `apa6` maintainer or the `endfloat` maintainer (`apa6` uses `endfloat` to deplay the floats).

The main issue is that if we can to write utf8 to disk, we need the data to be protected before it is written, else special chars get expanded.

This seems to help, placed in the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\efloat@iwrite[1]{%
   \expandafter\immediate\expandafter\protected@write\csname efloat@post#1\endcsname{}}

\makeatother
```

I changed `\write` to `\protected@write` and added `{}` after `\csname` as this macro expects three arguments not just two.

Edit: Hmm, looking at the generated code, no this does not write utf8 to disk, but it seems to compile correctly.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, @daleif. I tend to prefer the workaround proposed by @AndrewSwann, but I agree that this might be a more general issue and will thus contact the authors of `apa6` and `endfloat`.